# sed + match line and add word on the first string in line

Tags: sed

I have the following file

```
    more file
    machine1  network netmask  broadcast
```

how to add the "_NAME" after the first word in the line that have the "network netmask  broadcast" words ?

remark sed also need to match only "network netmask  broadcast" and then to add _NAME to the first word in the line

example: what I need to get after execute sed command

```
   machine1_NAME  network netmask  broadcast
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, since we're not using the `g` modifier, it'll only match once per line

```
sed -e 's/^[^ ]*\>/&_NAME/'
```

It matches non-space characters up to the first word boundary, replacing it with itself and appends `_NAME`. As mentioned, without the `g` modifier it'll only match once per line, and if there are leading white space on the line, just remove the first `^`-anchor.

**Edit**
you only wanted it to match on specific lines, so here goes:

```
sed -e '/network netmask broadcast$/s/^[^ ]*\>/&_NAME/'
```

The first part is a selector, which makes sure the substitution is only performed on lines where `network netmask broadcast` ends the line. To have it match any lines with those words, just remove the `$`-anchor, and add `*` (space-asterisk) to the spaces to make them flexible. But you probably already knew that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/network.*netmask.*broadcast/s|^\([ \t]*\)\(.[^ \t]*\) |\1\2_NAME|' file
```

Comment: @roe: Some versions of `sed` don't require the `-e`.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to be helpful, the -e is never wrong, but it may very well be incorrect to not use it, i.e. using it will pretty much always be safer. My bad.

Comment: @Dennis; yes, but unfortunately not all. I'm pretty sure Solaris sed does require it, and there's no mention of GNU sed in there.

Comment: fyi I think the -e is only necessary when you supply more than one instruction on the command line.  When there is only 1 instruction sed can figure that out without the 'e'